# Why this bash script with `while [expr]` won't run?

Tags: bash, fibonacci

When I try to run the script I get a "line 9: [2: command not found" error. This is my first bash script so I'm a complete beginner.

```
#!/bin/bash

num1=0
num2=1

count=2


while [$count -le $1]
do
num3='expr $num1+$num2'
num1=$num2
num2=$num3
count='expr $count+1'

done

echo "Fib Num: $num3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat t.sh
```

Shows:

```
#!/bin/bash

num1=0
num2=1

count=2

while [ $count -le $1 ]; do
  num3=$(expr $num1 + $num2)
  num1=$num2
  num2=$num3
  let count++;
done

echo "Fib Num: $num3"
```

Results:

```
$ bash t.sh 9
Fib Num: 34
```

The `[` and `]` need spaces, and the `expr` command should be wrapped within `$(` and `)`, rather than single quotes. You probably meant to use backticks (`), but don't use backticks anymore.

Since you're using bash, you can simplify increasing the count, too, as shown.

Comment: this is frustrating.. im getting "line 10: [: 2: unary operator expected" now

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: @user2012751: Try removing the spaces in while condition between `$count` and `-le` and `$1`: `while [ $count-le$1 ]`. Does it work now?

Comment: @ForbiddenOverseer: The spaces should not matter. In fact, the spaces are supposed to separate the different parameters to the `test` program (which is aliased to `[`).

Comment: @ormaaj: Any suggestions for improvement (i.e., suggest some alternatives) so that we can all learn something?

Comment: er yes, I suppose the difficulty in answering is there's a bash shebang but they're using ancient Bourne syntax anyway. I'll just type up the usual answers for this real quick.

Answer (score 6):

Add spaces around the `[` and `]`. `[` is a command, so it has to be a separate word. From `man bash`:

```
test expr
[ expr ]
       Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on  the  evaluation  of  the
       conditional  expression expr.  Each operator and operand must be
       a separate argument.  Expressions are composed of the  primaries
       described  above  under  CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS.
```

Comment: it is also good to add `set -e` to abort script execution on errors. And `set -x` to get a trace of what is going on.

Comment: The "unary operator expected" is probably due to $1 being empty. You need to check it's not empty before that point.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here are something resembling the "usual" ideal answers to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Bash/ksh93
# Theoretically also zsh/mksh, but both have bugs that break it.
function fib1 {
    # It is critical to validate user input if it will be used in an arithmetic
    # expression.
    [[ $1 == +([[:digit:]]) ]] || return 1

    # Demonstrates an accumulating version to print the intermediary results.
    typeset i=1 f=(0 1)
    while (( i < $1 )); do
        # Don't use expr(1) unless you're coding for Bourne.
        (( f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i++] ))
    done
    echo "${f[@]}"
}

fib1 "$1"
```

It is confusing that in addition to the broken syntax, you're using strange `expr` even with a `/bin/bash` shebang. You should read the bash manual and not read whatever suggested that to you.

```
#!/bin/sh

# POSIX (posh/bash/zsh/all kshes)
# It's easier to write a let wrapper than re-type test expressions repeatedly.
# This emulates let precisely, but it's not important to understand everything
# going on here. Breaks in dash because of its lack of support for the
# otherwise ubiquitously supported comma operator, and busybox because of a bug in
# its environment assignments.
let() {
    IFS=, command eval test '$(($*))' -ne 0
}

fib2() {
    # Uglier validation for POSIX
    case $1 in
        *[^[:digit:]]*|'')
            return 1
    esac

    # Using globals for simplicity
    count=$1 n1=0 n2=1
    while let count-=1; do
        let n1=n2 n2=${n1}+n2
    done

    printf 'Fib Num: %d\n' "$n2"
}

fib2 "$1"
```

My arithmetic fibonacci is somewhat popular as a curiosity.

```
# Bash/ksh93/zsh
# Could be more elegant but includes bug workarounds for ksh/zsh
 $ a=a[++n%20]=a[n]+a[n-1],a[0] a[n=2]=1; let a a=0; echo "${a[@]}"
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584

# Less portable because of bugs. Works in Bash.
 $ a=('a[a[n]=a[n-1]+a[n-2],n++/20]' 2 0 1); echo "${a[@]:n=4,a}"
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's probably a bit much for a "complete beginner," yet a very worthwhile study. Nice use of `((` and `))`; and the validation is a great idea. Wish I could vote this up more.